# Limit involving $(\cos x)^{1/x^4}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, trigonometry

I am having trouble calculating the following limit.

$$\lim_{x \to 0}(\cos x)^{1/x^4}$$

In *Problems in mathematical analysis* by *Demidovich* there is a hint that in case of $1^{\infty}$ indeterminate symbol in certain limit, one can add a term $a(x)$ which for given limit approaches zero and then after manipulation with exponents, it's easy to obtain a result of $e^{p}$, $p \in \mathbb{R}$.

My computations in this way lead to the result of $e^{0} = 1$, but WolframAlpha says this limit equals $0$.

If anyone could give me at least hints or solution for this problem, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Is it $\;\frac1x\;$ or $\;\frac1{x^4}\;$ in the exponent?!

Comment: @Constructor, why and how did you decide the exponent *must* be $\;1/x^4\;$ and not $\;1/x\;$ ??

Comment: I have made the mistake, the exponent containst $x^4$

Comment: Thanks @Max...still interesting to know how constructor knew that.

Comment: @DonAntonio It is all my sixth sense.

Comment: @DonAntonio Simply 4th power wasn't in the header of the question. But it was in the statement of the problem. See my revision more carefully.

Comment: I'd rather take your sixth sense explanation, @Constructor, since why would the question's header be wrong and the question's body right and not the other way around? :)

Comment: @DonAntonio To be honest I could not imagine that it might be the other way around. :)

Comment: Fair enough, @Constructor...jeje. +1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Rewrite the term in question as

$$\cos(x)^{\frac{1}{x^4}}=e^{x^{-4}\log(\cos(x))}$$

Now use that $\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^4)$ as $x$ approaches $0$ and look at the Taylor series of $\log(1+x)$ at $0$.

Comment: It's not the first time I see a neat solution with asymptotics, I'd like to read more about it. Could you recommend me a source to learn some basics? I'm an undergrad engineering student.

Comment: Any analysis undergrad text book should do.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log\cos x}{x^4}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\sin x}{4x^3\cos x}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\cos x}{12x^2\cos x-4x^3\sin x}=-\infty$$

Comment: ANother nice solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to0}(\cos x)^{\dfrac1{x^4}}=\lim_{x\to0}(\cos^2x)^{\dfrac1{2x^4}}$$

$$=\left(\lim_{x\to0}(1-\sin^2x)^{\left(\frac1{-\sin^2x}\right)}\right)^{\left(-\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin^2x}{2x^4}\right)}$$

Now as $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\left(1+h\right)^{\frac1h}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e,$ the inner limit goes to $e$

Again, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin^2x}{2x^4}=\frac12\cdot\left(\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}x\right)^2\cdot\frac1{\lim_{x\to0 }x^2}=\frac12\cdot1\cdot\infty$

Comment: @Max, how about this?

Comment: bhattarcharjee. Interesting problem, indeed but who is wrong ? The question is open to discussion.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, why wrong?

Comment: Some seem say that the limit is zero, other seem to say that it is infinity. I really do not know what to think ! Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, others have reached at $e^{-\infty}=0$,. I also have reached at $e^{-(\infty)},$ right? In the second limit calculation, I've left out the '-'

Comment: Sorry for that ! I missed it; unfortunately this happens (too) often to me because of my condition.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, nothing to be sorry.No harm in clearing doubt which may help other readers as well

Answer (score 0):

You received interesting answers so, I shall just report numerical results obtained using infinite precision.

For $x=\frac{1}{10}$, the value of the logarithm of the expression is -50; for $x=\frac{1}{100}$, it is $-5,000$; for $x=\frac{1}{1000}$, it is $-500,000$; for $x=\frac{1}{10000}$, it is $-50,000,000$ and so on. I suppose you notice the beautiful factor of $100$ everytime $x$ is divided by $10$.

On the other side, as suggested by TooOldForMath, if you develop as a Taylor series the logarithm of the expression around $x=0$, the expansion (for the logarithm) is $$-\frac{1}{2 x^2}-\frac{1}{12}-\frac{x^2}{45}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ from which you can conclude that the limit of the expression is $0$ as given by Wolfram Alpha and other answers to you post.

Thanks for the interesting problem !